# Azure log analytics rest API call error 403

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I'm getting below error(Intermittent) for azure log analytics API call.

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "The provided credentials have insufficient access to perform the requested operation",
        "code": "InsufficientAccessError"
    }
}
```

If I try with the same access token sometime it works.

Comment: Please show how did you request the token, and which API did you call.

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur when the token presented for authorization belongs to a user who does not have sufficient access to this privilege. Verify your workspace GUID and your token request are correct, and if necessary grant IAM privileges in your workspace to the AAD Application you created as Contributor.

A successful POST request to the AAD Token endpoint can get you the access token, which you can then use to call the Log Analytics API.

A sample request with a sample query would look like this:

```
POST /subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/{workspace-name}/api/query?api-version=2017-01-01-preview
Host: https://management.azure.com
Content-Type: application/json
Prefer: response-v1=true
Authorization: Bearer <token>

{ 
        "query": "Perf | where CounterName == 'Available MBytes' | summarize avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)",
        "timespan": "PT12H"
}
```

Please check [this](https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/1-Tutorials/ARM-API) doc for a detailed explanation.